# How do I launch MyApp automatically when I open a different app?

Tags: ios, swift

Goal: when I open a specific app, it automatically opens MyApp first before I can proceed to the specific app.

Say I want to open my Gmail app. When I click Gmail, before Gmail can open, I want to open/display MyApp that says "Hey - are you sure you want to open up Gmail right now?" first as a reminder. Then, I can click "Yes" and continue on to opening Gmail. Does Apple let you do this?

Comment: Not possible (at least using public APIs).

Comment: Short answerer? Absolutely not. Sandboxed apps in iOS. Now, you *can* do something a bit opposite of what you want... have another app open your app. It's called deep-linking.

Comment: Thanks for your help rmaddy and dfd. Too bad! I understand why they block that capability, but it'd be nice to do as part of their digital wellness movement.

Comment: The answer is pretty much simple. Its not possible and will not be possible in future also. Imagine if we can do that, then for all our competitors app we can force them to open our app thus making the use of applications a useless one.